# super in object literals

Tags: typescript, typescript1.6

ECMAScript 6 introduces some enhancements for object literals. One of them is `super` which references the prototype object.

In the following MDN document it is said:

> The super.prop and super[expr] expressions are valid in any method definition in both classes and object literals.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

The specification:
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-super-keyword

So this code:

```
var obj = {
    __proto__: {
        method() {
            console.log('original');
        }
    },
    method() {
        super.method();
        console.log('new');
    }
};

obj.method();
```

should log the following into the console:

```
original
new
```

But TypeScript 1.6.2 doesn't even compile it saying it's an error:

```
'super' can only be referenced in a derived class.
```

Does it mean TypeScript is not compatible with ES6 in this case?

Comment: Looks like you've found a bug in TypeScript, report an issue in the github

Comment: Thanks @gilamran. I did: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5441

Comment: One of you should post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a bug in TypeScript.

For reference see the issue on github:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5441